# As I can format a sentence in exp reg?

Tags: python, regex

as I can remove the phrase "abc def" of a paragraph in regular expression? considering that it may be prefixed by scores.

For example:

```
Hello, abc def, etc etc -> Hello, etc etc
abc def etc etc -> etc etc.
abd def ... etc etc -> etc etc.
Hello, abc def. Etc etc -> Helo. Etc etc
```

Considered that it might contain before or after the following characters: ,;.:

I've tried this:

```
msg = re.sub("\s+abc\s+def\s+", " ", msg)
```

But I need to create conditional Rating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[ ]*abc\s+def\s*[,;.:]*
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uE3cC4/19#python

Comment: My exp reg not works: msg = re.sub("[\s\.,;\:]abc\s+def[\s\.,;\:]", " ", msg) but your exp works fine. Why?

Comment: @WHK `[\s\.,;\:]*abc\s+def[\s\.,;\:]*` in ur regex `[\s\.,;\:]` should be `[\s\.,;\:]*` so that 0 or more can appear.In your regex if it not present it will fail